# ColdFusion EncodeForHTML and newlines

Tags: replace, newline, coldfusion-10, html-encode, carriage-return

What characters do newlines (\n) and carriage returns (\r) get converted to when using EncodeForHTML in ColdFusion? I have tried everything I can think of (or find online) but cannot find what I need to use in my REReplace statement to convert to break (br) tags after the encoding (I need to do this for display purposes).

What I would like to do is something like

```
#REReplace(EncodeForHTML(myVar), "html encoded newline etc chars", "<br />", "all")#
```

However, because I can't figure out what the newlines and carriage returns are being converted to the only way I can get it to work it to do a REReplace before and after EncodeForHTML, which doesn't seem very sensible or efficient. For example:

```
#REReplace(EncodeForHTML(REReplace(myVar, "\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r", "<br />", "all")), "&lt;br &##x2f;&gt;", "<br />", "all")#
```

I am using CF 10.

Answer (score 6):

\n is being encoded as `&#xa;`

\r is being encoded as `&#xd;`

So the following simplified code now works:

```
#REReplace(EncodeForHTML(myVar), "&##xa;&##xd;|&##xd;&##xa;|&##xa;|&##xd;", "<br />", "all")#
```